# How to set up a derived repo with git and git-flow?

Tags: git, git-flow

I've got a main repository that's the core game engine and now I need to make another repository that will end up being an actual game. Because I'll be using git-flow for both, I can't just fork the original and pull/push whenever I need the changes to the engine. What I need preferably is to be able to take the changes that are on the master branch in the engine repo and merge those changes to the develop branch in the derived project. How would I set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this got my project set up exactly the way I wanted it and allows me to update the copy of the main project whenever I want to: http://debuggable.com/posts/git-fake-submodules:4b563ee4-f3cc-4061-967e-0e48cbdd56cb

If anyone else wants to use this but runs into problems with pulling new versions of the base project, stash your changes before you pull.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). Looks like this is what suits your need.

Comment: With the issues git submodules come with, I would like to avoid using them.